# postgres CASE and where clause

Tags: postgresql

Suppose i have a table like:

```
id  item  type  status  date
1   A     1     P       2018-04-01
2   B     2     A       2018-01-01
3   C     1     A       2018-01-02 
4   D     2     A       2018-04-11
```

Now query 1:

```
Select count(case when type=1 and status='A' and date<'2018-04-01' then id) as type1, 
count(case when type=2 and status='A' and date<'2018-04-01' then id)as type2
FROM table
```

AND query 2:

```
Select count(case when type=1 then id) as type1, 
    count(case when type=2 then id)as type2 
FROM table where status='A' and date < '2018-04-01'
```

are these both same, if yes whcih is better

Comment: Please add your current table schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an index on the `date` column, then the second version would probably perform better than the first version.  The reason for this is that Postgres would be able to filter off many records in the `WHERE` before even having to do the conditional aggregations in the `SELECT` clause.

If `date` doesn't have an index, then Postgres would have to touch every record in the table in either case.

Answer (score 0):

With an schema like this:

> ```
> create table tbl
> (
>     id     int primary key,
>     item   text,
>     type   int,
>     status text, 
>     date   date
> );
>
> insert into tbl values
> (1, 'A', 1, 'P', '2018-04-01'),
> (2, 'B', 2, 'A', '2018-01-01'),
> (3, 'C', 1, 'A', '2018-01-02'),
> (4, 'D', 2, 'A', '2018-04-11');
> ```

Second query performs a bit better due:

```
Rows Removed by Filter: 2
```

But neither of them use any index, for a large amount of data you should consider to add a new index and check performance again.

> ```
> explain (analyze,buffers)
> select count(case when type = 1 and status = 'A' and date < '2018-04-01' then id end) as type1, 
>        count(case when type = 2 and status = 'A' and date < '2018-04-01' then id end) as type2
> from   tbl;
> ```
>
> ```
> | QUERY PLAN                                                                                            |
> | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Aggregate  (cost=33.40..33.41 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.022..0.022 rows=1 loops=1)              |
> |   Buffers: shared hit=1                                                                               |
> |   ->  Seq Scan on tbl  (cost=0.00..17.80 rows=780 width=44) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=4 loops=1) |
> |         Buffers: shared hit=1                                                                         |
> | Planning time: 0.171 ms                                                                               |
> | Execution time: 0.121 ms                                                                              |
> ```

> ```
> explain (analyze,buffers)
> select count(case when type=1 then id end) as type1, 
>        count(case when type=2 then id end)as type2 
> from   tbl 
> where  status = 'A' 
> and    date < '2018-04-01';
> ```
>
> ```
> | QUERY PLAN                                                                                         |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Aggregate  (cost=21.71..21.72 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.007..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)           |
> |   Buffers: shared hit=1                                                                            |
> |   ->  Seq Scan on tbl  (cost=0.00..21.70 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=2 loops=1) |
> |         Filter: ((date < '2018-04-01'::date) AND (status = 'A'::text))                             |
> |         Rows Removed by Filter: 2                                                                  |
> |         Buffers: shared hit=1                                                                      |
> | Planning time: 0.084 ms                                                                            |
> | Execution time: 0.032 ms                                                                           |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=844e24172cc312c358a1cd9639c02162)*